# Great Lakes story where fisherman and dog search islands for a show dog

Tags: identification-request

Read this story in the early 70s. Set around the Great Lakes area in the US. A local fisherman and his trusty pet Labrador dog are searching small islands trying to find a famous show winning Labrador dog that has gone missing or feral, to claim a large reward from its owner. Always thought it was a Jack London story as I read *Call of the Wild* and *White Fang* around the same time. Been through the JL wiki and can't find a match.

The story may have been set on Lake Erie.

The show dog was perfect in every way as a black Lab but had a small white patch on chin/chest that the judges would overlook. The main character was slowly going broke as a fisherman so the reward was important to him. He never finds the show dog but his own female Lab does and nature takes it course. The litter of pups, with the white chin patch, solves his financial woes.

Comment: The Great Lakes area extends from Minnesota to New York, can you narrow it down any more? Can't you remember *anything* else about the story, like whether they find the missing dog or not? Do you recall the names of any of the characters, human or canine?

Comment: Lake Erie feels right. The show dog was perfect in every way as a black Lab but had a small white patch on chin/chest that the judges would overlook. The main character was slowly going broke as a fisherman so the reward was important to him. He never finds the show dog but his own female Lab does and nature takes it course. The litter of pups, with the white chin patch, solves his financial woes.